Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to Activate my controller
As From MERN Stack Background i am finding Dotnet tough, i created controllers and registered my DBContext as i am attempting to save my data in mysql db but still i am facing this issue, can you spot where i did mistake.
Program.cs(my main file):
public Program(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"),
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 0))));

    services.AddControllers();
}

Controllers/MyDbContext.cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Raiders.Api.Models;

namespace Raiders.Api.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

Controllers/SignupController.cs
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SignupController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public SignupController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SignupUser(string username)
        {

            var newUser = new User
            {
                Username = username
            };

            _context.Users.Add(newUser);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok("User created successfully");
        }
    }
}

Controllers/User.cs
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}


What is the error message you get? And why is this taged with wpf (windows presentaion foundation) as there is no relation to wpf in your code?

Your program.cs is quite weird to me. I think inject configuration to "program" class is the problem.
For a typicall webapi project. If the SDK you use is >= ".net6", you should register services and access configuration like below:
program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(
            builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"),
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 0))));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
...
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.Run();

If you use .net5 or lower, then you should inject in "Startup.cs" in like following:
Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
...

Reference : https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-2-comparing-webapplicationbuilder-to-the-generic-host/
